# Listener on Atomic Sequence

Tags: java, caching, ignite

Is it possible to listen Apache Ignite's put, get and increment on [Atomic Sequence](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/data-structures/atomic-sequence#atomic-sequence)? If not, is there any other way to do such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to listen to AtomicSequence events, however, you can use update a regular cache for each sequence update, then listen to EVENT_CACHE_PUT, thereby achieving the same functionality.

https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/data-structures/atomic-sequence

```
//create an atomic sequence
IgniteAtomicSequence seq = ignite.atomicSequence("seqName", // Sequence name.
        0, // Initial value for sequence.
        true // Create if it does not exist.
);

// Increment the atomic sequence.
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    long currentValue = seq.get();
    long newValue = seq.incrementAndGet();

   //RECORD the sequence value in a regular cache
   ignite.getOrCreateCache("myCache").put(ignite.cluster().localNode().id(), newValue)
}
```

Then listen to EVENT_CACHE_PUT as described here:
https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/events/listening-to-events#listening-to-remote-events